# references for the spectral theorem

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Recently, I am thinking about the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32417/9464) in spectral theory. And I finally found that I need help with the [properties of unitary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator#Properties). Its a consequence of the spectral theorem for the normal operator, as the wiki says. The spectral theorem in the book I have ever read is only for self-adjoint operator and without many details.

> **Could anybody here recommend me some
>   references for this theorem?**

Comment: This is not exactly what you need, but I think it's worth mentioning anyway: Halmos' article *What does the spectral theorem say?", here: http://www.jstor.org/pss/2313117 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reed and Simon, *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics*, Volume 1, Chapter 8.

Comment: I would have mentioned Reed and Simon, but their treatment of the spectral theorem is for self-adjoint operators, the version for normal operators (which is what Jack was asking about) being relegated to the exercises.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too. (So it is perhaps a bit strange that the answer which does not exactly answer the question is accepted.)

Comment: @Robert: you are probably right. I don't have my copy handy so was giving the reference based on memory + TOC, the former of which may likely have confused exercise for statement. @Wild: even stranger happens on this site at times.

Answer (score 5):

Rudin, "Functional Analysis", chapter 12

Answer (score 4):

Conway, *Functional Analysis*, Chapter IX.

Pedersen, *Analysis NOW*, Section 4.4 & 4.5.

Lang, *Real and Functional Analysis*, Chapters XVIII, XIX, XX (yes this is a long book!).

Comment: I might add that Pedersen and Conway cover normal operators, while Lang only treats self-adjoint operators.