# Is there an injective operator with a dense nonclosed range?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

> Is there an operators $A \in B(H)$ such that  $Im(A) \subsetneq \overline{Im(A)} = H$ and $Ker(A) = \{0\}$ ?

**Bonus** : We can build such operators by using some compact or shift operators (see the answers).
Is there others possibilities ?
How classify this phenomenon ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check that for
$$
T:\ell_2\to\ell_2: (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\mapsto(1^{-1} x_1,2^{-1}x_2, 3^{-1}x_3,\ldots)
$$
we have $\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\{0\}$, $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(T)}=\ell_2$, but $T$ is not surjective because $(1,2^{-1},3^{-1},\ldots)\notin\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Comment: thank you for this canonical example.

Comment: More generally, any compact operator $A:\ell_2\to \ell_2$ with ${\rm ker}(A)=\{ 0\}$ does the job. The range of $A$ is infinite-dimensional because $A$ is $1$-$1$, and so ${\rm Im}(A)$ cannot be closed because it would then be isomorphic to $\ell_2$ and this would give a compact isomorphism from $\ell_2$ onto itself.

Comment: No. If you take $T=Id\oplus A$ acting on $\ell_2\oplus\ell_2$ with $A$ as above, then $T$ has the required properties but it is not compact.

Comment: Thank you Etienne for this generalization. What is the set of all such operators ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux We can say it is the set of all operators such that $0$ belongs to their [continuous spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Continuous_spectrum). Other than that...

Comment: Thank you @julien. I had forgotten that we can [decompose the spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29) into a point, continuous and residual spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of the *[continuous spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29)* $\sigma_{c}$ (possibly empty) :
$\forall \lambda \in \sigma_{c}(T)$ , $T-\lambda I$ is injective with nonclosed dense range.

**Example**: the shift

Let $H=l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $S \in B(H)$ defined by $S.e_{n} = e_{n+1}$, called the **shift**.
It's well-known that $\sigma(S) = \sigma_{c}(S) = \mathbb{S}^{1}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/spectrum-of-right-shift-operator)).   So $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$, $S-\lambda I$ is such an operator.